# How to display content in next column after a specific no. of rows?

Tags: css, jsp

[image]

I am using this kind of code to display items from database:

```
<!-- HTML code-->
<%
    //rest of the java code
    while(rs.next())
    {
%>

    <p><%=rs.getString("item")%></p>

<%
    }
    //rest of the java code
%>
<!-- HTML code-->
```

I want the output to be something like in the image so that after 5 rows the item name move to next column.

How to I do this?

Comment: Make a demo of your code here. edit > put html > run and then update

Comment: I have posted the main code. It has JSP code, not just HTML @Justcode

Comment: can't you run html only? fyi, seeing your image seems `float:left` to your `<p>` will work and adjust width as per your requirement.

Comment: No. The item names are from database. I haven't applied any HTML or CSS on this part. The code in the question is the one concerned here.

Comment: I the items are being displayed in loop. @Justcode

Comment: And I am not using any tables @Justcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may set an `height` to set numbers of lines : `line-height` * numbersOfLineWanted + `padding`/`margin` applied to tags ( mind `box-sizing`).

Set a `column-width` value and give same `width` to element.

```css
ul {
  width:100px;
  -moz-column-width:100px;
  -webkit-column-width:100px;
  column-width:100px;
  height:6.5em;
}

/* demo show */
ul {
  border-left:solid;
  padding:0;
  counter-reset:lis;
}
li {
  display:block;
}
li:after {
  counter-increment:lis;
  content:' ' counter(lis);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

---

or use the flex `display` :

```css
ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:6.5em;
  width:0;
}

/* demo show */
ul {
  border-left:solid;
  padding:0;
  counter-reset:lis;
}
li {
  display:block;
  width:100px;
}
li:after {
  counter-increment:lis;
  content:' ' counter(lis);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: <li> or<p> , whatever you need a container and childs to store in columns :)